# Sort and print integers fed from keyboard in ascending order without using arrays in C

Tags: c, sorting

The task is to sort and print the integers input from keyboard in ascending order, without using arrays in C . The end of inputs is marked by a '-1', which is not to be taken as an input. 
I have tried to solve this but could not succeed, can anyone help me solve this problem?

Here is my attempt

```
#include<stdio.h>

void smaller(int first,int second)
{
    int temp=0;
    if(second<first) {
        temp=first;
        first=second;
        second=temp;
        printf("%d %d",first,second);
        }
}

int main()
{
      int first=0,second=0;

      printf("Kindly enter numbers to be arranged in ascending order followed by a -1\n\n");
      scanf("%d",&first);

      while(second != -1) {
          scanf("%d",&second);
          smaller(first, second);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect recursion is needed or save the data to a file - unless input is in the order needed.

Comment: What about a linked list?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That's an approach that would be very welcomed at https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: Pick a data structure that allows quick traversal in a sorted order.  Put the input in that data structure.  Output the data in order.

Comment: Use binary search tree.

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/zSdwCG)

Comment: I was about to say the same thing with @BLUEPIXY . Binary Search Tree is the proper way.

Comment: @GeorgeBou Get used to it, he is one of the fastest guns in the west (or on SO, so to speak). *Rumor has it, BLUEPIXY is actually a bot that scans incoming questions automating correct answers on the fly...*

Comment: Do you intend to sort a stream of integers using just 2 variables and no external storage? If yes, then I'm sorry to say it's not possible, unless the user just enters 2 input numbers, in which case you might as well have used an array of 2 integers.

Comment: Thanks all for confirming what I believed, I also think it is not possible to do this without using any data structure like an array or a linked list. Initially I thought it might be possible recursively, but no .

Comment: Binary search tree does solve it , thanks BLUEPIXY. But again it uses a data structure 'structs', also the output contains unwanted extra lines (which can be ignored , for practical purposes).

Answer (score -3):

In this, we can enter each number one by one from keyboard then perform insertion sort on ech step, finally we get an sorted set of numbers.

Comment: This would be a very time consuming program (regarding complexity etc.). And still, you would probably need to use an array.